# How to show a FancyBox video on a Google Map marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I have a simple app with a Google Map and markers.
Clicking on the markers i have to show either an image, a slideshow or a video.

This is the javascript needed to display an image (properly working):

```
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    $.fancybox({
   href: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Tootsi_jaamahoone.jpg/800px-Tootsi_jaamahoone.jpg'
              // other options

                });     
            });
```

This is instead the attempt i have made to display a video:

```
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
              $.fancybox({
                  'type' : 'iframe',
                  // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
                  'href' : 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_W1apjU4Go',
                  'overlayShow' : true,
                  'centerOnScroll' : true,
                  'speedIn' : 100,
                  'speedOut' : 50,
                  'width' : 640,
                  'height' : 480
              });    
            });
```

Here i have recreate the situation with a Google Map with 3 markers, for one of them is possible to see an image, for the other a slideshow, for the third a video.
The image and the slideshow are working properly, but instead of the video i am seeing a blank box:

http://jsbin.com/ANuyojoW/13/edit

Someone perhaps knows how can i properly display a video?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following js:

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ANuyojoW/14)

```
// Video - Not working 
google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
              $.fancybox({
                  'type' : 'iframe',
                  // hide the related video suggestions and autoplay the video
                  'href' : 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_W1apjU4Go'.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
                  'overlayShow' : true,
                  'centerOnScroll' : true,
                  'speedIn' : 100,
                  'speedOut' : 50,
                  'width' : 640,
                  'height' : 480
              });    
            });
```